# Python 2.7 and random

Tags: python, random

I am trying to run the following code...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random

def randomList():
    l = []
    for i in range(0, 20):
        l.append(random.randint(-100, 100)
    return l 

def displayList (l):
    for i in l:
        print (i)

listeAleatoire = randomList()

displayList( listeAleatoire )
```

However, at the return it show me the following error:

```
"[...], line 8 return l SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
     ^
```

I am a bit helpless, maybe you could help, before I get all my hair away... Thank you!

Comment: add the missing closing parenthesis at the end of this line: `l.append(random.randint(-100, 100)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis on this line:

```
l.append(random.randint(-100, 100)
                                  ^-- should be one more here
```

So Python complains about the return statement because it thinks it's still within the parentheses from the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

I reformated the code for you. You should close all open blackets. See the comment inside the script.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random


def randomList():
    l = []
    for i in range(0, 20):
        l.append(random.randint(-100, 100)) # close the bracket!
    return l


def displayList(l):
    for i in l:
        print (i)


listeAleatoire = randomList()

displayList(listeAleatoire)
```